# How do I compute the area of Steinmetz solid?

Tags: surfaces, parametrization

I want to compute the area of  the boundary of the solid $x^2+z^2\leq 1$ and $y^2+z^2\leq 1$ to compute his surface afterwards. But I somehow don't see how. First I thought about polar coordinates, then cylinder-coordinates and then splitting the solid up, but somehow nothing worked.

Could someone give me a hint? It would be really nice.

Thank you for your help

Comment: I think your solid has a boundary that can be expressed as $z = \pm \sqrt{ 1 - \max(x, y)^2}$

Comment: I thought that if we only need to compute the boundary of the solid shouldn't it only be the following two equations: $x^2+z^2=1$ and $y^2+z^2=1$? But also in this case I have some troubles to procede

Comment: This is a classical issue about the [Steinmetz solid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinmetz_solid) and its surface area ($16$).

Comment: Yes sure but I need to compute it with the method i described in the comment below the answer

Comment: I have taken the liberty to include the name "Steinmetz" in your title:  can be useful later one for people looking for similar issues or simply to attract them to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to parametrize one smooth surface out of a total of four pieces.

$$r(u,v) = (\cos u, v, \sin u)$$
where $ |u| \le \pi/2 $ and $ |v| \le \cos u $. The latter is derived from $ v^2 \le 1 - \sin^2 u$.

The derivatives of the surface are

$$r_u = (-\sin u, 0, \cos u)\\
r_v = (0, 1, 0)$$
Hence, the cross product of them is $ r_u \times r_v = -(\cos u, 0, \sin u) $ whose Euclidean norm is $ |r_u \times r_v| = 1 $.

By definition of surface area $S$, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_area)

\begin{array}{cl}
S &= \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_{-\cos u}^{ \cos u} |r_u \times r_v| dv du\\
&=4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{ \cos u} 1 dv du\\
&=4\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos u du\\
&=4
\end{array}

Finally, the sum of all pieces of the same area is $4 \times 4 = 16$.

More comments: From the condition $x^2 + z^2 = 1$, we can easily get the main structure of $r(u,v)$. Now, what matters here is the domain of the function $r$, where $y^2 + z^2 \le 1$ comes into play. Substituting $y = v$ and $z = \sin u$ gives the valid domain of the function.

Comment: sorry could you maybe explain again how you get to this parametrisation

Comment: And if I want to compute the surface with the gram matrix as I described below in a comment can I take the same parametrisation?

Comment: sorry I quite do not see how to get there

Comment: @Strandkorb This answer is doing as you suggested, and taking $(1)$ from my parameterisation and multiplying by $4$.  It does so in a very clever way that avoids any difficult integration (+1).

Comment: @tkf yes the idea is clear but I don't see how to get to this parametrisation

Comment: but why can we do this exaclty like this? because in all the other exampels it was clear but here I'm totally lost and I don't like this at all

Comment: I'm sooooooo sorry but I don't get it.

Comment: @Strandkorb The last comment I can give you now is 'try to draw it yourself.' ;)

Comment: I just draw it several times and nothing helped.

Comment: so for me it is clear that if i denote $y=v$ then $z=cos(v)$ by the equation $y^2+z^2=1$ but I don't see how to get x. and why do you have a u? in my opinion it would be $(\sin(v),v,cos(v))$

Comment: I have drawn a picture in my answer, which may help. $x=\sqrt{1-z^2}=\sqrt{1-\sin^2 u}=\cos u$

Comment: So but this circle in the picture exactly cuts along the y-z plane right?

Comment: Yes but the point $(y,z)$ in the picture represents the point $(x,y,z)$ on the surface of the boundary.

Comment: ah okei, but then could I define $\phi:[0,1]\times [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ where $\phi(v,\theta)=(\cos\theta,v,\sin\theta)$ but then I need to multiply by 8 right

Comment: Almost - but $v\in[-\cos(\theta),\cos(\theta)]$, not in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Hmm I don't get it, i uploaded my picture in the question. So when I want to compute the red area, I know that a point in the "back plane" has coordinates $(y,z)=(v,\sin\theta)$ But now I need the angle which moves in the red area right? so I get that $x=\cos(\theta)$ but then v goes from 1 to $\sin(theta)$ doesn't it?

Comment: $y^2+z^2\leq1$ so $y\in [-\sqrt{1-z^2},\sqrt{1-z^2}]=[-\cos\theta,\cos\theta]$.

Comment: but is my picture correct?  And then with this intervalls I need to multiply it by 8 at the end or only by 4

Comment: If you integrate over $\{(v,\theta)|v\in[-\cos\theta,cos\theta],\theta\in[0,\frac\pi2]\}$ then you multiply by $8$ at the end.

Comment: but is there a way to see it geometrically, because if I only see the intervalls I wouldn't multiply by 8, only by 4.

Comment: We multiply by a factor of $4$ because there are $4$ disks, and by a factor of $2$ because you had $\theta\in [0,\frac\pi2]$, so we are only covering half the disk.  In Hermis14' parametrisation $\theta\in [-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2]$.

Comment: Ah and if we use hermis14‘s parametrisation we only need to multiply by 4 right?

Comment: @tkf I really admire your passion for this community. Thumbs up.

Comment: Yes exactly, by $4$.

Comment: Oh wow perfect ghank you

Answer (score 2):

I would divide this surface into $4$ pieces, each parameterised by a disk:

\begin{eqnarray*}
&(1)&\qquad y^2+z^2\leq 1,\qquad x=\sqrt{1-z^2}\\
&(2)&\qquad y^2+z^2\leq 1,\qquad x=-\sqrt{1-z^2}\\
&(3)&\qquad x^2+z^2\leq 1,\qquad y=\sqrt{1-z^2}\\
&(4)&\qquad x^2+z^2\leq 1,\qquad y=-\sqrt{1-z^2}\\
\end{eqnarray*}

You can visualise this as $(1)$ being the right of the solid, $(2)$ the left, $(3)$ the back and $(4)$ the front.

Clearly the $4$ pieces cover the entire boundary, as for a point to be on the boundary of the solid, at least one of the equalities $y^2+z^2\leq 1$ or $x^2+z^2\leq 1$ must be attained.

Hermis14's parameterisation:

[image]

Comment: I thought that if we only need to compute the boundary of the solid shouldn't it only be the following two equations: $x^2+z^2=1$ and $y^2+z^2=1$? But also in this case I have some troubles to procede

Comment: @Strandkorb No - think about the boundary of a square: $x^2\leq 1, y^2\leq 1$.  It has $4$ pieces: $x=1, y^2\leq 1$ and $x=-1,y^2\leq 1$, and $y=1, x^2\leq 1$ and $y=-1,x^2\leq 1$.  If you combine the equations to get $x^2=1, y^2=1$ this just gives the $4$ corners of the square, not the boundary.

Comment: but then why did you have one equality and one inequality?

Comment: @Strandkorb Intuitively it is a bit like the Leibniz rule $(fg)'=fg'+f'g$, where when you differentiate a product, you differentiate one term and leave the other, then go the other way.  Here to take the boundary of the solid defined by the two inequalities, you let one equality be attained and leave the other, then go the other way.  Another way of seeing this is that to be on the boundary of your solid, it suffices that either one of your inequalities is attained.

Comment: See my comment.

Comment: okei so if I want to compute the surface it's enought to do it for only one parametrisation and then multiply the result by 4 right? But how do I get a parametrisation with a function from your (1) because we have the formula $A(\phi)=\int_Q \sqrt{g_\phi(x)}dx$ where $g_\phi$ is the determinant of the gram matrix

Comment: You would integrate over the disk $\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right)^2}$, where $f(y,z)=\sqrt(1-x^2)$.  I do not know if the integrable ends up being manageable.  If you prefer to integrate over triangles, rather than disks, you could use the excellent parameterization given by @lisyarus: into an octahedron.  That comment gives two pieces initially - a unit square top and unit square bottom.  However these squares need to each be subdivided into $4$ triangles, depending on which is greater out of $x^2$ and $y^2$.

Comment: In fact you can compute everything in an octant and multiply the result by $8$.